# add POI to groovy/java on linux

Tags: groovy

running a groovy script on Linux, none of the HSSF and XSSF imports work. e.g.

```
   import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell
unable to resolve class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell
```

I tried adding poi-3.9-20121203.jar to the GROOVY_HOME/lib and Java share /usr/share/java.

Comment: Have you added the jar to the script's path?

Comment: The issue was unique to XSSF and not HSSF. wrong jar!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xssf` classes are in the `poi-ooxml` jar file.  You can download it here:

```
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.poi|poi-ooxml|3.9|jar
```

Or alternatively, use `@Grab`:

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='org.apache.poi', module='poi-ooxml', version='3.9')
)
```

Comment: Good catch :-)  I always prefer omitting the `@Grapes` bit and just using the short form: `@Grab( 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.9')`

Comment: True, the short version is nicer.  In this case I cut and pasted the shortcut from maven central.

Comment: The issue was indeed with the xssf not where I put the jar. All the answers were useful

Answer (score 2):

Don't stick things in `GROOVY_HOME/lib` or `/usr/share/java`, you'll just end up with a mess that you can't replicate on another machine when the time comes to move it all...

You don't say how you're running the script, or if it;s a self contained script, but assuming it is, try adding

```
@Grab( 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.9' )
```

To the top of your Groovy script (above the `import`s)

Comment: Try adding the grab, if that doesn't work, you'll need the Jar, and  the right versions of it's dependencies `log4j`, `commons-logging` and `commons-codec`.  Then add them all to the classpath (separated by colons on Linux)

Answer (score 1):

Documentation > Getting Started > Quick Start > [Running](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Running)

### Adding things to the classpath

When running command line scripts or interactive shells you might want to add things to your classpath such as JDBC drivers or JMS implementations etc. To do this, you have a few choices:

- Add things to your CLASSPATH environment variable
- Pass -classpath (or -cp) into the command you used to create the shell or run the script
- It's also possible to create a ~/.groovy/lib directory and add whatever jars you need in there.
- If the jars you need are in a Maven or Ivy repository, you can "grab" them with Grape.

---

`groovy -cp path-to-poi-3.9-20121203.jar`